# NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification not being dispatched

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an implementation of Core Data where I need to listen to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification, but it simply doesn't get dispatched.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
           addObserver:self 
              selector:@selector(method:) 
                  name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
                object:nil];
```

In my implementation if I switch to the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` everything works as expected, ie, my `method:` selector gets invoked.

To trigger the notification, I'm simply doing this:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription 
               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object" 
                        inManagedObjectContext:_moc];
if (![_moc save:nil]) { 
  NSLog(@"saving successful, expecting notification dispatch");
}
```

But nothing... Please halp

EDIT: If I manually post the notification `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` inside the save `if` statement, it gets dispatched and my `method:` gets called, but my `NSManagedObjectContext` just won't do it automatically on save as it should...

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219340/nsmanagedobjectcontextdidsavenotification-not-triggered-in-ios-7

Comment: no, my problem is that the notification doesn't even get dispatched.  I've tried moving everything to the same thread, same thing.  what's really odd to me is the willSaveNotification gets dispatched normally but not the didSave-

Comment: Does your `NSLog` print the "saving successful" message? You didn't say, and it might be important.

Comment: i literally just found the problem before i read your post.  i'm retarded...

Comment: @Tom Harrington just wanna say thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the save was actually returning an error. So obviously it didn't save.